# Convert low poly mesh to high poly mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shape-keys

I am working on a game development project where I need to animate a character. Originally we purchased this asset made using Max 3D (I am using rigged fbx file for my game). Due to incompatibility in rig I have to import fbx into blender and export it again in unity, so that it works correctly.

Up till now its working fine, but now I want to convert low poly character to a high poly character. I am not sure how to do it accurately, I have tried using subsurface modifier but it is not letting me apply modifier because mesh is using shape keys. I don't know how to remove shape keys, IF I even should remove shape keys or not.

Is there a way to make my mesh high poly without breaking anything related to my flow till now, like texture mapping, weight paint or anything. I don't know enough about Blender or 3D modelling in general to make any change which needs a lot of rework.

Comment: hello, why do you need to convert it to a high-poly mesh?

Comment: @moonboots my game only has 1 character which does different animation (it isn't actually a game but more of a module integrated in other project). When doing these animations, character many times ends up with hard edges, which my clients wants to remove. I can add an image if you want to see what it looks like during animation.

Comment: You can try adding a subdivision modifier to your model but depending on how it was modelled, you might get an ugly result. Usually the workflow is High poly > Low Poly, the other way around isn't possible because the information is already lost, you'll have to add it back yourself which will be some work to achieve